# Why is Wendy considered young to join the fairy tail guild

Tags: fairy-tail

I realize Wendy is young but it seems like Natsu Gray and Erza where younger than she is when they're in the flashbacks and they were in the guild at the time and Lisana was even younger since Mirigane was Erza's age, so why is everyone like "she's so young".

Comment: well considered FT have around 100 member, perhaps they are the only one who join them in such young age, so their reaction doesn't feel too strange

Comment: so like no one since the olden days has joined at such a young age??

Comment: probably, we know that Lucy, Gajeel, Juvia join FT when they were older. Probably most of the member are like that. Well normally you don't need to work till you got older, since guilds are also the place to get a job

Comment: Are you sure "Wendy is young" is mentioned for joining the guild? Afaik, its because she is young, but she is a powerful Dragon Slayer with "Healing Magic" which is incredibly rare. So more of a surprise thing. If she was "too young to join", Erza would never have invited her!

Comment: it seems like they are talking about joining but i suppose they could be saying she's so young to be so powerful but  its always seemed like they were saying she was young to be in a guild. but if they were talking about being a strong mage natsu gray and erza seemed much more powerful even when they were young so then the question simply shifts to why are they so suprized at a young powerful mage